# Filter date time with substring and date object

Tags: javascript

I have this string `2022-02-25 06:09 AM`. How do I use return just `06:09 AM` (without seconds)?

I tried two ways. One way is to convert the string into Date object and then use `toLocaleTimeString`. But the output is `6:09:00 AM` which includes the second. Here is my code.

```
getMyTime(lastUpdate) { 
    let d = new Date(lastUpdate);
    return d.toLocaleTimeString();
},
```

The other way is I used substring which returns `25 06:09 AM`. Not sure why it get `25`. Here is my code.

```
getMyTime(lastUpdate) { 
    return lastUpdate.substring(19,8);        
},
```

Comment: Given the date part is a fixed length, how about simply `str.substring(11)`? See [String.prototype.substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

Comment: Try `.split()` by a space character, then append index `[1]` and `[2]`.

Comment: ya split works. thanks.

Comment: hi steve, `Date` has [`getHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours) and [`getMinutes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMinutes) methods to retrieve the values independently.

Comment: `str.substring(11)` works.

Answer (score -1):

Use options like this:

```
getMyTime(lastUpdate) { 
    var options = { 
      hour12: true, // false if you want hour without AM or PM (24 format)
      hour: '2-digit',
      minute: '2-digit'
    };

    let d = new Date(lastUpdate);
    return d.toLocaleTimeString("en-GB", options);
}
```